# Trying to access nested array using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Currently working on a practice project where I am utilising the angular knowledge I have gathered and continue gathering through the online courses I am taking.

I am having a bit of trouble accessing a nested array. I saw an online tutorial and I have followed the basis of what was shown but I am obviously not doing something right. The code is shown below.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="classic-movie" ng-repeat="films in movies">

        <div class="movie-summary">

            <div class="movie-image">

                <img ng-src="{{films.cover}}" class="movie-thumbnail">

            </div>

            <div class="movie-name-plot">

                <h1>{{films.title}}</h1>

                <p>{{films.plot}}</p> 

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>{{films.starring}}</p>

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>{{films.runtime}}</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="movie-showtimes">

            <ul class="movie-timing mon-timings" ng-repeat="timing movies.monTimings">

                <li>{{timing.time1}}</li>
                <li>{{timing.time2}}</li>
                <li>{{timing.time3}}</li>
                <li>{{timing.time4}</li>
                <li>{{timing.time5}}</li>
                <li>{{timing.time6}}</li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And below is a template of the first object in the array.

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.controller("maincontroller", ["$scope", function($scope){

    $scope.movies = [

    {
        cover: "images/movie-images/ferres.jpg",
        title: "Ferris Bueller's Day Off (1987)",
        plot: "High school student Ferris Bueller wants a day off from school and he's developed an incredibly sophisticated plan to pull it off. He talks his friend Cameron into taking his father's prized Ferrari and with his girlfriend Sloane head into Chicago for the day. While they are taking in what the city has to offer school principal Ed Rooney is convinced that Ferris is, not for the first time, playing hooky for the day and is hell bent to catch him out. Ferris has anticipated that, much to Rooney's chagrin.",
        starring: "Matthew Broderick, Alan Ruck, Mia Sara",
        runtime: "103min",
        monTimings: [
        {
            time1: "10:45",
            time2: "13:10",
            time3: "15:45",
            time4: "18:25",
            time5: "20:30" ,
            time6: "21:50",

        }
        ]

    },
```

When I go to the view, the list in which the timings are supposed to be displayed are not there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing `in` at your second **ng-repeat**
2. You should **ng-repeat** on `films.monTimings` since `movies.monTimings` doesn't exist since `movies` is an array which doesn't have the `monTimings` property. Only the elements it contains has that.

So change this:

```
ng-repeat="timing movies.monTimings"
```

To this:

```
ng-repeat="timing in films.monTimings"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a nested array, we need two loops for iteration. 
You can achieve it by adding the second loop for monTimings in first div as below

```
          <div class="classic-movie" ng-repeat="films in movies">
             <!-- use existing block for films -->
                 <ul class="movie-timing mon-timings" ng-repeat="timing in films.monTimings">
                   <!--use timing to iterate monTimings  -->
                 </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in this line `<ul class="movie-timing mon-timings" ng-repeat="timing movies.monTimings">`.

It should be:

```
 <ul class="movie-timing mon-timings" ng-repeat="timing in films.monTimings">
```

You have forgotten `in` in `ng-repeat`.